# Adding wordpress post ID's to a persistant collection

Tags: php, jquery, wordpress, session, data-persistence

I am using wordpress posts with multiple custom meta to display may items. The items are searched for and added to a collection (or cart) This resembles a commerce solution which are widely used in wordpress I don't understand where they store the variables while the user continues to shop.

To expand further the user will search for items when they see the item they want they can click on it to open a detail view in a modal. Add some specific information (meta) to the item and then ADD to collection. They will then search again for more items and perform the same - all the time building their collection.

Once they are happy with the collection they have created they move to the publish page where I need to output the contents of the collection into a template of the users choice.

The main problems I am facing is being able to add the post ID's and modified meta to local storage / DOM / $_COOKIE etc, some advice on the best solution would be great.

I have searched high and low and I cannot find anything that does this without getting bogged down in useless ecommerce features.

Many thanks

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to do this is probably to set cookies.  The fantastic jQuery.cookie plugin [found here](https://github.com/carhartl/jquery-cookie) makes this a piece of cake - setting and retrieving cookies just takes one line of code:

To set:

```
$.cookie('cookiename', 'cookievalue');
```

To retrieve:

```
var whatever = $.cookie('cookiename'); // assigns 'cookievalue' to var whatever
```

You can also set them to expire after a set amount of time, etc (those are session cookies above).  If you need to store arrays (e.g. of post IDs or meta values) the plugin also lets you store JSON objects as cookies. See the documentation on the page I linked for details.

Comment: Ok happy with the storage - many thanks... However how can I set the cookie value to be the post ID? Basically on.Click set the current post ID to be cookie-1. I was considering if it would be better using a form to enter the custom meta and then GET?

Comment: Easiest way is to output the post ID into the DOM somewhere in the loop (PHP `echo get_the_ID()`) then grab it with JS. Most WP themes do this already (e.g. `<article id="post-67">` which you could grab with `$('article').attr('id');` and use that value to set the cookie.